# Toxic FX Flow - how to avoid it

Tags: fx, quant-trading-strategies, high-frequency, quants

So, basically i want to debate and find out the real reason behind being flag by ECNs and venues as "toxic". How to avoid being flag? What kind of strategies are toxic and why?

Below is an article found by a brokerage firm... so the opinion in that article couldn't be that objective.

Article about toxix FX flow

Any thoughts?